# Openquery where in clause

Tags: openquery

I am using  a openquery. I tried the following syntax:
where table.column in ('''''+@parameter+''''') but still report does not work when I select multiple parameters.
Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `@Parameter` is like this:

```
DECLARE @Parameter NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Parameter = 'one value'
SET @Parameter = 'first value,second value,....,last value'
```

First put your query statement into a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @TSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(connection, ''SELECT * FROM dbo.table WHERE table.column IN (''' + @Parameter + ''')'')', ',', ''',''')
```

and then execute it with

```
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @TSQL
```

**Note:** @TSQL must be NTEXT, NCHAR or NVARCHAR!!!

Comment: Yes I have put the sql statements in variables like that but the problem is the report does not show anything I select multiple values for parameter. If I select single parameter, it shows up. I am using IN operator like you but I didn't get that extra commas you have used

Comment: From your comment, I presume that you are using OPENQUERY SQL statement in a SQL Server Report Services report (.rdl), am I right? If that's the case, please confirm and I'll try to revise my answer according to that.

Comment: I am using OPENQUERY in stored procedure.

Comment: But from where do you call this stored procedure makes all the difference. For example in my answer you can send either one or by using commas to seperate more values than one value to the @Parameter which could easily be turned into a stored procedure. If you would share the whole script of your stored procedure, we could work from there.